# highstock series.stochastic "k d" in different colors

Tags: highcharts

Would like to have K% in Red and D% in yellow on stochastic series.

[Would like to achieve this look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4ltc.png)

Comment: Hi @Gaetano Siano, Could you explain your problem more precisely? Also, some minimal live example with your chart configuration options would be very useful.

Comment: Hi, had not noticed I can could set the smoothedLine color.  All good, thank you.
``````````````````````````````````````````
   color: 'red',
            smoothedLine: {
                styles: {
                    lineColor: 'yellow'
                }
            }
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0):

set color:"yellow" and lineColor:"red" where you define your stochastic serie